# Unknown column issues in database

Tags: php, mysql

please help me with this issue i'm having. I get 'Unknown column 'the_mother_church_id' in 'where clause' .
I have check several times the name of the column name in the database, and i'm sure the name is same.

Please where could the problem be.

Thanks

```
<?php
   $past = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM the_mother_church WHERE the_mother_church_id = '1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

**CREATE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `the_mother_church` (
  ` the_mother_church_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `the_mother_church_head` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ` the_mother_church_content` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
  ` the_mother_church_tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ` the_mother_church_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  ` the_mother_church_image` blob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: can you show us the CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `the_mother_church` ( ` the_mother_church_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `the_mother_church_head` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ` the_mother_church_content` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
  ` the_mother_church_tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ` the_mother_church_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  ` the_mother_church_image` blob NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: @user1365922: Could you can edit your question (see the 'edit' link just under the tags?) and paste it in there instead so that it's more readable?

Comment: @user1365922: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement appears to show the column was named with a space between the opening quote and the field name: `' the_mother_church_id'` (or is that just my imagination)?

Comment: @eggyal your suggestions is correct. Can you give it in a proper answer, so i can mark it. Thanks.

Comment: @user1365922: Already done, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

Your `CREATE TABLE` statement shows the column was named with a space between the opening quote and the field name: `` ` the_mother_church_id` ``.  Either:

1. Use the column name with a space in your query:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM the_mother_church WHERE ` the_mother_church_id` = '1'
   ```
2. Rename the columns:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `the_mother_church`
     CHANGE ` the_mother_church_id`
             `the_mother_church_id`      int(255)      NOT NULL,
     CHANGE ` the_mother_church_content`
             `the_mother_church_content` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
     CHANGE ` the_mother_church_tags`
             `the_mother_church_tags`    varchar(255)  NOT NULL,
     CHANGE ` the_mother_church_created`
             `the_mother_church_created` datetime      NOT NULL,
     CHANGE ` the_mother_church_image`
             `the_mother_church_image`   blob          NOT NULL;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Check the name of the field again. I also advise you to wrap the field name in backticks.

Comment: Given that the OP said he's already checked it several times and that `the_mother_church_id` is definitely **not** a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, I'm not too sure that this answer is particularly helpful...

Comment: If the field is exist in the table, it's error in the SQL-query where this field is uses.

Comment: Turns out when he checked it several times he was wrong, and he *should* have checked the field again. Valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in front of the field name in your table structure.
I'd suggest to re-create a table, removing spaces from the field names.

```
` the_mother_church_id`
 ^ an excessive space
```